# How does outlook count load times?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have a vsto outlook add-in which I have been having some load problems with on some computers, usualy around 700-1500ms. I need to do some initialization which takes some time, on my computer it takes around 200-300ms. It was single threaded so the main function took the same time and the event logger showed that plus 50-100ms which seemed okay as the vsto probably takes some time to start etc.

Then the confusing thing appeared. I took that slow function and put it in it's own thread and what happened with the main function time? It now took around 3ms. Great! Looked in the event logger and the load time for the add-in hasn't changed a bit! So the question is how does outlook count the load times if it's not for running the main function and wait for input? Is the other thread also counted? Should I instead use a timer that does the init?

I must have the init function at start-up as we should not display out button if it did not initialize. So I could of course delay it for 500-1000ms but thats about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your addin is written in .Net, and it is the first such addin to be loaded, you will take a hit for loading the .Net run-time. There is nothing you can do about that...